# It should print true if the second argument is fully contained within the first argument, but it prints false

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  char *str1, *str2;
  int str1len, str2len; 
  str1 = argv[1]; str2 = argv[2];
  str1len=strlen(str1);
  str2len=strlen(str2);

  if (str2len>str1len){
    printf("false\n");
    return 0;
  }
  char sub1[100];
  for (int i=0;i<str1len-str2len;i++){
    strncpy(sub1,str1+i,str2len);
    if (strcmp(sub1,str2)==0){
      printf("true\n");
    }
    printf("false\n");
    return 0;
  }
}
```

I don't know what part of it is wrong that it doesn't work.
This is the question: a program that takes two text strings as arguments and prints "true" followed by a newline if the second string is entirely contained within the first, or "false" followed by a newline otherwise.

Comment: How about concatenating a space before and after?  Treat `"pre"` as `" pre "`.

Comment: One approach could be: add a space to the beginning and end of the search string (`"this is pretty"` => `" this is pretty "`) and the word (`"pre"` => `" pre "`). Then simply do a strcmp.

Comment: @CompuChip I edited the question, so apparently my code works only for some cases. for example it doesn't work for 'I am the walrus' 'I am the walrus'

Comment: Have you printed out everything to make sure the program is seeing what you expect it to see?  `printf("arg1 = [%s] (%d); arg2 = [%s] (%d)\n", str1, str1len, str2, str2len);` — after the first paragraph of code.  Have you considered using `strstr(str1, str2)` to determine the result?

Comment: Your `strncpy()` calls could be causing problems — it isn't clear why you're using `strncpy()` instead of plain `strcpy()`.  You should check that `100` is big enough before you proceed, anyway.  You should add some sample inputs (and the expected and actual outputs) to your question.  That's an important part of creating an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: Actually, when the code is indented correctly and the last close brace `}` is added, it becomes clear that the problem is that the `print("false\n"):` is inside the loop, along with the `return 0;` that terminates the program.  You need those two statements outside the loop.  Indentation does matter; it makes such problems more easily spotted.  And despite Google's coding standards requiring it, a 2 space indent is not really big enough for comfort — use 4 spaces (if you don't go for the Linux kernel's tabs-for-indentation with tab stops assumed to be 8 spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `str1len` >= `str2len`, when you do `strncpy(sub1, str1+i, str2len)` it isn't copying over the null terminal character. Add one to the end as such.

```
strncpy(sub1, str1+i, str2len);
sub1[str2len] = '\0';
```

Also, the indexing is off-by-one. If your `str2` happens to be located at the end of `str1`, it will not be caught by `str1len-str2len`. Instead it should be

```
str1len-str2len+1
```

The completed code being:

```
char sub1[100];
for (int i=0; i < str1len-str2len+1; i++){
    strncpy(sub1, str1+i, str2len);
    sub1[str2len] = '\0';
    if (strcmp(sub1,str2) == 0){
        printf("true\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
printf("false\n");
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of problems, you did not added 0 character and your loop was too short. Fixed example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  char *str1, *str2;
  int str1len, str2len;
  str1 = argv[1]; str2 = argv[2];
  str1len=strlen(str1);
  str2len=strlen(str2);

  if (str2len>str1len){
    printf("false\n");
    return 0;
  }
  char sub1[100];

  int i = 0;
  for (;i < (str1len-str2len) + 1; i++){
    strncpy(sub1, str1+i, str2len);
    sub1[str2len] = '\0';

    if (strcmp(sub1,str2)==0){
      printf("true\n");
      return 0;
    }
  }
  printf("false\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your comment about `for (int i = 0; i < (str1len - str2len) + 1; i++)` not being C has been incorrect for the whole of the current millennium.  It was a feature adopted into C99.  Of course, not all compilers used in the current millennium use C11 or even C99 by default; some still only use C90, or use C90-mode by default.  But that is a problem with the compiler, not with the C language.  Note too that declaring `sub1` where you do is not allowed in C90, but is OK in C99.

Answer (score 1):

Use printing to help debug your code — or use a debugger to do printing similarly.  This is the code I came up with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s 'haystack string' 'needle'\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    char *str1, *str2;
    int str1len, str2len;
    str1 = argv[1];
    str2 = argv[2];
    str1len = strlen(str1);
    str2len = strlen(str2);
    printf("str1 (%d): [%s]\n", str1len, str1);
    printf("str2 (%d): [%s]\n", str2len, str2);

    printf("strstr() says '%s'\n", (strstr(str1, str2) == 0) ? "false" : "true");

    if (str2len > str1len)
    {
        printf("false\n");
        return 0;
    }
    char sub1[100];
    if ((size_t)str2len >= sizeof(sub1))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Oops: the needle is too big (%d > %zu)\n", str2len, sizeof(sub1));
        return 1;
    }
    memset(sub1, 'X', sizeof(sub1)-1);
    sub1[sizeof(sub1)-1] = '\0';        // Demonstrated problem with lack of null terminator
    for (int i = 0; i <= str1len - str2len; i++)
    {
        strncpy(sub1, str1 + i, str2len);
        sub1[str2len] = '\0';           // Null terminator that prevents some problems!
        printf("Compare [%s] with [%s]\n", sub1, str2);
        if (strcmp(sub1, str2) == 0)
        {
            printf("true\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("false\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled from `subs61.c` to `subs61` and run, I get, for example:

```
$ gcc -m64 -g -O3 -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wshadow \
>     -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith  -Wold-style-definition \
>     -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes subs61.c -o subs61
$ subs61 'I am the Walrus' 'I am the Walrus'
str1 (15): [I am the Walrus]
str2 (15): [I am the Walrus]
strstr() says 'true'
Compare [I am the Walrus] with [I am the Walrus]
true
$ subs61 'He said, "I am the Walrus", but did you believe him?' 'I am the Walrus'
'subs61' is up to date.
str1 (52): [He said, "I am the Walrus", but did you believe him?]
str2 (15): [I am the Walrus]
strstr() says 'true'
Compare [He said, "I am ] with [I am the Walrus]
Compare [e said, "I am t] with [I am the Walrus]
Compare [ said, "I am th] with [I am the Walrus]
Compare [said, "I am the] with [I am the Walrus]
Compare [aid, "I am the ] with [I am the Walrus]
Compare [id, "I am the W] with [I am the Walrus]
Compare [d, "I am the Wa] with [I am the Walrus]
Compare [, "I am the Wal] with [I am the Walrus]
Compare [ "I am the Walr] with [I am the Walrus]
Compare ["I am the Walru] with [I am the Walrus]
Compare [I am the Walrus] with [I am the Walrus]
true
$
```

(Hmmm: I ran this in a different directory from where I normally work on Stack Overflow questions and the compilation options in the `makefile` are even more stringent than I normally show.)

Note that the copy'n'compare code is doing a lot more work than is strictly necessary; the `strstr()` solution is much more sensible.  You could rework the loop to avoid copying and use `strncmp()` — that would be analogous to what `strstr()` does.

```
    printf("Using strncmp():\n");
    int spotted = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= str1len - str2len; i++)
    {
        printf("Compare [%.*s] with [%s]\n", str2len, str1+i, str2);
        if (strncmp(str1+i, str2, str2len) == 0)
        {
            printf("true\n");
            spotted = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!spotted)
        printf("false\n");
```

The code should be packaged into a function (or several functions) called from the main program, which would simplify some aspects of the code.  For example, the `spotted` variable wouldn't be needed.  The functions would probably not print `true` or `false`; they'd return a value and the calling code would be responsible for the printing.

Comment: You are an amazing programmer Jonathan!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by using the C string.h function strstr(). It searches for a 'needle' string in a 'haystack' string, strstr(haystack,needle). It returns a pointer to the location of the start of the needle in the haystack. If it can't find the needle, then it returns a null pointer. You can basically achieve what you want by testing for,

```
if(strstr(argv[1],argv[2]) == NULL){
  printf("false\n");
} else {
  printf("true\n");
}
```

I think the problem in your code is that the `printf("false\n"); return 0;` are exiting your function prematurely. You're not testing all the possible start positions for str2. Try this,

```
for (int i=0;i<str1len-str2len;i++){
  strncpy(sub1,str1+i,str2len);
  if(strcmp(sub1,str2) == 0){
    printf("true\n");
    return 0;
  } 
}
printf("false\n");
return 0;
```

Now you only get to the `prinf("false\n");` statement after testing every start position for str2.

Comment: I 100% agree that `strstr()` is the simplest and correctest way to go.  Your revised loop still fails the `"I am the Walrus"` test.  You need `i <= str1len - str2len` or `i < str1len - str2len + 1`.  You also have problems with null-terminated strings.

Comment: In his specific example, I’m pretty sure strncpy() will pad his buffer variable sub1 with null characters. I assumed that he chose a 100 character size for sub1 because it would always be bigger than his inputs, and thus trigger the null character padding. I didn’t try it out though. It’s certainly possible that I’m reading too much into stncpy() ‘s functionality. The for loop end point is certainly a bug, but it wasn’t his major issue. It was having the print false and exit statements the loop. I should have checked though for a fence post error instead of trusting his math.

Comment: Because the length given in the `strncpy()` is not the size of `sub1` but the length of the second string, there's no null padding.  If you remove the null assignment after `strncpy()` in the code in my answer, you can run the code and see what I mean.

Comment: My bad. Misread the behaviour of strncpy() when I was double checking it. That’s what you get for answering stack overflow before your morning coffee. !)